# Thymeleaf template unable to parse my html 5 page correctly

Tags: html, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am developing a web application using Spring framework and gradle as the build tool. I am using Thymeleaf as the front end template engine. My code for my login page looks like this:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
  xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<meta name="description" content="Bootstrap"/>
<meta name="author" content=""/>

<title>Login</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo:400,700,400italic"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/fonts/linecons/css/linecons.css" th:href="@{assets/css/fonts/linecons/css/linecons.css}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/fonts/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" th:href="@{assets/css/fonts/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" th:href="@{assets/css/bootstrap.css}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/xenon-core.css" th:href="@{assets/css/xenon-core.css}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/xenon-forms.css" th:href="@{assets/css/xenon-forms.css}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/xenon-components.css" th:href="@{assets/css/xenon-components.css}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/xenon-skins.css" th:href="@{assets/css/xenon-skins.css}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/custom.css" th:href="@{assets/css/custom.css}"/>

<script th:src="@{assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js}" src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js" th:src="@{https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js}"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js" th:src="@{https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js}"></script>
<![endif]-->


</head>
<body class="page-body login-page login-light">
<div class="login-container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-6">

            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function($)
                {
                    // Reveal Login form
                    setTimeout(function(){ $(".fade-in-effect").addClass('in'); }, 1);


                    // Validation and Ajax action
                    $("form#login").validate({
                        rules: {
                            username: {
                                required: true
                            },

                            passwd: {
                                required: true
                            }
                        },

                        messages: {
                            username: {
                                required: 'Please enter your username.'
                            },

                            passwd: {
                                required: 'Please enter your password.'
                            }
                        },

                        // Form Processing via AJAX
                        submitHandler: function(form)
                        {
                            show_loading_bar(70); // Fill progress bar to 70% (just a given value)

                            var opts = {
                                "closeButton": true,
                                "debug": false,
                                "positionClass": "toast-top-full-width",
                                "onclick": null,
                                "showDuration": "300",
                                "hideDuration": "1000",
                                "timeOut": "5000",
                                "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
                                "showEasing": "swing",
                                "hideEasing": "linear",
                                "showMethod": "fadeIn",
                                "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
                            };

                            $.ajax({
                                url: "data/login-check.php",
                                method: 'POST',
                                dataType: 'json',
                                data: {
                                    do_login: true,
                                    username: $(form).find('#username').val(),
                                    passwd: $(form).find('#passwd').val(),
                                },
                                success: function(resp)
                                {
                                    show_loading_bar({
                                        delay: .5,
                                        pct: 100,
                                        finish: function(){

                                            // Redirect after successful login page (when progress bar reaches 100%)
                                            if(resp.accessGranted)
                                            {
                                                window.location.href = 'dashboard-2.html';
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });


                                    // Remove any alert
                                    $(".errors-container .alert").slideUp('fast');


                                    // Show errors
                                    if(resp.accessGranted == false)
                                    {
                                        $(".errors-container").html('<div class="alert alert-danger">\
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">\
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>\
                                                <span class="sr-only">Close</span>\
                                            </button>\
                                            ' + resp.errors + '\
                                        </div>');


                                        $(".errors-container .alert").hide().slideDown();
                                        $(form).find('#passwd').select();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    });

                    // Set Form focus
                    $("form#login .form-group:has(.form-control):first .form-control").focus();
                });
            </script>

            <!-- Errors container -->
            <div class="errors-container">

            </div>

            <div th:if="${param.error}">
                Invalid username and password.
            </div>
            <div th:if="${param.logout}">
                You have been logged out.
            </div>

            <!-- Add class "fade-in-effect" for login form effect -->
            <form th:action="@{/extra-login-light}" method="post" role="form" id="login" class="login-form fade-in-effect" autocomplete="on">

                <div class="login-header">
                    <a href="dashboard-2.html" th:href="@{/dashboard-2.html}">
                        <img th:src="@{assets/images/white.jpg}" src="assets/images/white.jpg" alt="" height="" width="180" class="logo"/>
                        <img th:src="@{assets/images/xm_lockup.png}" src="assets/images/xm_lockup.png" alt="" height="45" width="220" class="logonew"/>
                    </a>

                    <p>Dear user, log in to access the admin area!</p>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="passwd">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="passwd" autocomplete="off"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary  btn-block text-left">
                        <i class="fa-lock"></i>
                        Log In
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="login-footer">
                    <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>

                    <div class="info-links">
                        <a href="#">ToS</a> -
                        <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </form>

            <!-- Facebook Login
            <div class="external-login">
                <a href="#" class="facebook">
                    <i class="fa-facebook"></i>
                    Facebook Login
                </a>
                -->

                <!-- 
                <a href="<?php _hash(); ?>" class="twitter">
                    <i class="fa-twitter"></i>
                    Login with Twitter
                </a>

                <a href="<?php _hash(); ?>" class="gplus">
                    <i class="fa-google-plus"></i>
                    Login with Google Plus
                </a>
                 -->
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<!-- Bottom Scripts -->
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/resizeable.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/joinable.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/xenon-api.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/xenon-toggles.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/toastr/toastr.min.js"></script>


<!-- JavaScripts initializations and stuff -->
<script src="assets/js/xenon-custom.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I ran the code successfully, but the Css files, images and the scripts couldn't be loaded on the page, and hence it looks like an ordinary page with just a form. The page now looks like this [Page without any CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCL45.png). I reckon it is an issue with thymeleaf. What wrong have I done? Please go through the code and rectify the mistakes.

The project structure now looks like this:-
[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPAjG.png)

Comment: Check in the developer tools of browser if `CSS` was loaded. If not it can be bad route: th:href="@{assets/css/custom.css}"

Comment: I did as you said. Yet, the result is the same. I have now changed the project structure by relocating the css files to the static folder. I made the static folder as the root directory. I have attached a photo of how the structure appears now. Please go through it and the code, and let me know what is wrong in them.

Answer (score 1):

Check in the developer tools of browser if CSS was loaded. If not it can be bad route:

```
th:href="@{assets/css/custom.css}"
```

Try that:

```
<link th:href="@{/css/fileName.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
```

and the file should be located in:

```
\your_project\src\main\resources\static\css\fileName.css
```